# C lang - sprintf creates 8 char-long string instead of 6, when applied to negative int

Tags: c

I am at a loss to understand why the following piece of code would print ffffffff (8 characters), instead of ffffff. Could anyone please explain to me?

Thanks,
LC

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char string[100];

    sprintf(string, "%06x", -1);
    printf("The string was formatted as: %s\n", string);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf(string, "%06x", -1);` prints *at least* 6 characters.  `%x` implies an unsigned number.  `(unsigned) -1`, in hex, is `FFFFFFFF` on a 32-bit `unsigned` machine.

When `scanf()` gets to the `"%06x"`, "The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd; ..." C11dr §7.21.6.1 8

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that %x implied an unsigned number. Is there any easy way to print -1 to ffffff? Or should I try to write my own function for that?

Comment: May I just truncate the first two chars from ffffffff? Or is this incorrect?

Comment: 0xffffff is not -1.  If you converted unsigned 0xffffff to signed, you would not magically get -1.  There's no 24-bit datatype that would let you do this.  If that's your convention, you can hand-code around it, but IMO this would confuse most programmers to do it this way.

Comment: Here is a bit of context: I am doing some coursework to write an assembler. I need to convert the operands (signed numbers) to a 24 bit hexadecimal number using twos-complement. So in the case where the operand is -1, may I use sprintf with the format "%06x" (as in my initial post) and truncate the first two characters when the operand is negative?

Comment: Rather than doing truncation on the text, "truncate" the variable first: `int ToInt24(int x) { return x & 0xFFFFFF; } sprintf(string, "%06x", ToInt24(-1));` or some other wrapper?

Comment: chux, thank you very much. This is much better indeed.

Comment: @user3006803 A _portable_ solution would use `long` as `int` is only at least 16 bits.  `long ToInt24(long x) { return x & 0xFFFFFFL; } sprintf(string, "%06lx", ToInt24(-1));`  Another option is type `int32_t`.